# Web API Notification requireInteraction is not working in Electron App for Windows

Tags: javascript, angular, web, notifications, electron

I am using Web API Notification in my electron app following [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

My code looks like this:

```
notifyMe() {
   var msg = "Notification Check!!!";
   var options = {
     body: '',
     requireInteraction: true,
     sticky: true
   }
   // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
   if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
   }

   // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
   else if (Notification['permission'] === "granted") {
      var notification = new Notification(msg,options);
      notification.onclick = (event)=> {
        //some action
      };
   }

   // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
   else if (Notification['permission'] !== "denied") {
      Notification.requestPermission((permission)=> {
        // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
        if (permission === "granted") {
           var notification = new Notification(msg,options);
           notification.onclick = (event)=> {
             //some action
           };
        }
     });
   }
}
```

After saving all the code, I made a build for Windows Platform using Electron Packager using the command :

```
$ electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=ia32
```

Although, as per Mozilla Documentation, I have mentioned the

```
requireInteraction: true, sticky: true
```

However, both of these options are working fine in Chrome browser but unfortunately, these options are not working in the Electron build an app for Windows.

The Notifications are showing but they do not wait for any user interaction and gone.

Is there any other library for showing sticky notifications in Windows platform, which stick to the screen unless the user performs any action?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.